# Custom pdf plugin for internet explorer, firefox ,chrome etc

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, pdf, plugins, google-chrome

I want to write a custom plugin which can open a pdf file for popular browsers(IE , Firefox, Chrome). I am going to  use some open source pdf viewer code if I can and put some checks in that code for authentication and license validity.

Actually the plugin should work with many file types(Video, audio, doc etc...), I am trying to develop one for pdf as a start.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of help do you need? With the plugin itself or the pdf reading/rendering part?

Comment: actually both. I have no understanding how to do any of those two. Can we make the plugin to be downloaded each time user tries to open a pdf(if it is small in size), else download and install it once.

Comment: The answer to your question is beyond the scope of this site.  Entire books have been written about extension development, and you want three books—one for each browser you mention.  Go start writing it, and when you have *specific* questions come back and ask those questions instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should research NPAPI and ActiveX, which are how browser plugins are developed for all browsers but IE, and IE, respectively. Then, as suggested in the comments, come back when you have specific questions.